# How to correctly select multi-columns from a return of a function in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, pgadmin, set-returning-functions

I have hundreds of tables with same structure in a Postgresql-11 db, and I need to perform a
same statistics on each of them.

Since the real statistics logic is very complex, in order to simplify my question in here, let's say I need to calculate MAX/MIN/MEAN/STDDEV of each.

I don't want to edit individual SQLs for each single table one by one, since if so I would code hundreds lines of very similary SQL, with an only difference at the table name.

So I used dynamic SQL in a function to do the calculation for one table a time, like this:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS get_features_for;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_features_for(
    IN  table_name VARCHAR,
    OUT result_ RECORD ) LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $func$

DECLARE sql_string VARCHAR :=
    format('
        SELECT ''%s'' table_name,     -- just for validating
            MAX(feature) max_feature,
            MIN(feature) min_feature,
            AVG(feature) avg_feature,
            STDDEV(feature) std_feature
        FROM "%s";',
        table_name, table_name );

BEGIN
  EXECUTE sql_string INTO result_;
END
$func$;
```

And then call it with every table names in the db, within a query, like this:

```
SELECT tbs."table_name", get_features_for( tbs."table_name" )
FROM information_schema."tables" tbs
WHERE tbs.table_schema = 'public' AND tbs.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
  AND tbs."table_name" LIKE 'analy%'
ORDER BY tbs."table_name";
```

It works, but the results are similar to the followings:

> "table_name", "get_features_for"
>
> "analy_001",  "(analy_001,-3,2,0,2.5)"
>
> "analy_002",  "(analy_002,-3,2,-1,2)"
>
> "analy_003",  "(analy_003,-3,2,0,2)"

You can see that all the result columns have been wrapped into a single string column, and let me can **NOT** use them conveniently.

I want them to be similar to:

> table_name, max_feature, min_feature, avg_feature, std_feature
>
> "analy_001", "analy_001", -3, 2, 0, 2.5
>
> "analy_002", "analy_002", -3, 2, -1, 2
>
> "analy_003", "analy_003", -3, 2, 0, 2

How should I get that?

BTW, I'm using pgAdmin.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of the function is a composite type. The most efficient way to get the individual columns would be a lateral join:

```
SELECT tbs.table_name, f.*
FROM information_schema.tables tbs
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL get_features_for(tbs.table_name) AS f
WHERE tbs.table_schema = 'public'
  AND tbs.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
  AND tbs.table_name LIKE 'analy%'
ORDER BY tbs."table_name";
```

Avoid `*` and spell out the actual column names in your real query.

Comment: I appreciate it! You are good man!

Answer (score 0):

You *could* also do the following - it appears to be quite performant (It makes extensive use of quick string functions, no regexes - all of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/f72GQY4e)):

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  analysis TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Populate:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES 
('"analy_001", "(analy_001,-3,2,0,2.5)"'),
('"analy_002", "(analy_002,-3,2,-1,2)"'),
('"analy_003", "(analy_003,-3,2,0,2)"');
```

and then we run:

```
SELECT 
  SPLIT_PART(analysis, '", "(', 2)  -- do as much of the  work here as possible!
FROM test;
```

Result:

```
split_part
analy_001,-3,2,0,2.5)"
analy_002,-3,2,-1,2)"
analy_003,-3,2,0,2)"
```

And then:

```
SELECT
  REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(analysis, '", "(', 2), ')"', '')
FROM test_;
```

Result:

```
replace
analy_001,-3,2,0,2.5
analy_002,-3,2,-1,2
analy_003,-3,2,0,2
```

Finally, we run:

```
SELECT
  SPLIT_PART(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(analysis, '", "(', 2), ')"', ''), ',', 1) AS table_name,
  SPLIT_PART(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(analysis, '", "(', 2), ')"', ''), ',', 2) AS min_f,
  SPLIT_PART(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(analysis, '", "(', 2), ')"', ''), ',', 3) AS max_f,
  SPLIT_PART(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(analysis, '", "(', 2), ')"', ''), ',', 4) AS avg_f,
  SPLIT_PART(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(analysis, '", "(', 2), ')"', ''), ',', 5) AS std_f
FROM
  test_;
```

Result:

```
table_name  min_f max_f avg_f std_f
 analy_001     -3     2     0   2.5
 analy_002     -3     2    -1     2
 analy_003     -3     2     0     2
```

Of course, you'll have to feed in your values from your original SQL, but it appears to be quite performant:

```
SET enable_seqscan = OFF;
```

and then:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE, TIMING)
SELECT
  SPLIT_PART(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(analysis, '", "(', 2), ')"', ''), ',', 1) AS table_name,
  SPLIT_PART(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(analysis, '", "(', 2), ')"', ''), ',', 2) AS min_feature,
  SPLIT_PART(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(analysis, '", "(', 2), ')"', ''), ',', 3) AS max_feature,
  SPLIT_PART(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(analysis, '", "(', 2), ')"', ''), ',', 4) AS avg_feature,
  SPLIT_PART(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(analysis, '", "(', 2), ')"', ''), ',', 5) AS std_feature
FROM
  test_;
```

Result:

```
QUERY PLAN
Bitmap Heap Scan on public.test_  (cost=15.29..89.89 rows=1360 width=160) (actual time=0.028..0.034 rows=3 loops=1)
  Output: split_part(replace(split_part(analysis, '", "('::text, 2), ')"'::text, ''::text), ','::text, 1), split_part(replace(split_part(analysis, '", "('::text, 2), ')"'::text, ''::text), ','::text, 2), split_part(replace(split_part(analysis, '", "('::text, 2), ')"'::text, ''::text), ','::text, 3), split_part(replace(split_part(analysis, '", "('::text, 2), ')"'::text, ''::text), ','::text, 4), split_part(replace(split_part(analysis, '", "('::text, 2), ')"'::text, ''::text), ','::text, 5)
  Heap Blocks: exact=1
  Buffers: shared hit=2
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on t_ix  (cost=0.00..14.95 rows=1360 width=0) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=3 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=1
Planning Time: 0.164 ms
Execution Time: 0.100 ms
```

A brief diversion about SET enable_seqscan = OFF;.

- This doesn't actually disable sequential table scans, it just makes them very expensive - see discussion below.
- Do not do this on production systems, or at least don't do it globally. You could, if and only if you fully understand any consequences, do it on a case-by-case, query-by-query basis, but it's not to be recommended. Today's query hints are tomorrow's bugs - use with caution.
- The reason I'm doing it here is to force the optimiser to choose the index over a sequential scan. Without enable_seqscan = OFF, the very small sample tables here would cause the optimiser to automatically choose a sequential scan. With a large number of records on a production system, this should not be a problem.

From the documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html):

```
enable_seqscan (boolean)
```

> Enables or disables the query planner's use of sequential scan plan
> types. **It is impossible to suppress sequential scans entirely**<sup>(*)</sup>, but
> turning this variable off discourages the planner from using one if
> there are other methods available. The default is on.

<sup>(*) Emphasis mine</sup>